# How can I dynamically register and deregister vuex-module-decorators stores?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

I have a `vuex-module-decorators` decorated Vuex store. I want to be able to dynamically load and unload the module depending on which Vue component I am in, so that I don't have all stores loaded at the same time (only the ones in use).

```
@Module({
  namespaced: true,
  name: 'fooStore',
  store,
  dynamic: true,
})
class FooStore extends VuexModule {
    bar: string = 'hi';
}

export const fooStore: FooStore = getModule(fooStore);
```

With naked Vuex I can do this with `store.registerModule` and `store.deregisterModule`, calling them on the `beforeCreate` and `destroyed` Vue lifecycle hooks. This doesn't work with `vuex-module-decorators`, as `getModule` registers the store.

How can I register and deregister `vuex-module-decorators` decorated Vuex stores?